# Check if these $3$ vectors are linearly independent by using rule of Sarrus

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

> Given are $3$ vectors in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}^{3}$. Decide if these are
>   linearly independent by using rule of Sarrus.
>
> $$v_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  1\\  1 \end{pmatrix},
> v_{2}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  0\\  0 \end{pmatrix}, v_{3}=\begin{pmatrix}
> 0\\  1\\ 
> -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

I need to change in $v_{3}$ the $-1$ because $-1 \text{ mod }3 = 2$. So here is the first thing I'm not sure about. **Do I have to use Sarrus first and then change numbers (in case they don't equal 0,1 or 2) or rather change the number first and continue with Sarrus?**

Here I first change number and I'm not sure if that's ok.

$$v_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}, v_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}, v_{3}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Write this as $3 \times 3$ matrix and write it like Sarrus (write additionally $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$):

[image]

Now we need to calculate the determinant $D$ and if it doesn't equal zero then the vectors are linearly independent.

$$D=1 \cdot 0 \cdot 2+1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1+ 0 \cdot 1 \cdot 0-1 \cdot 0 \cdot 0- 0 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 - 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1$$

$$D=0+1+0-0-0-2=-1$$

And thus the vectors are linearly independent.

---

Is everything done correctly here? Because we write an exam soon and I need to know if I can do it like this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first question, it's OK if you keep the $-1$ and change the result of the determinant in case it's not $0$, $1$ or $2$, or proceed as you've done. There is no difference. The calculations seems fine to me.